# mouse down stuck on some programs in linux gnome

Tags: linux, mouse, gnome

I use arch linux with Gnome.

It looks like some programs think the left mouse button is kept down even though it isn't.

Now this affects a handful of programs (other ones run fine, so mouse is not guilty):

- Libreoffice (but so far, only in calc for the tabs that allow switching spreadsheet: it thinks I'm trying to move them)
- Darktable (sliders move without having been clicked)
- Telegram (messages get selected when mouse pointer goes over the message window)

I usually run the following programs:

- firefox + chrome
- eclipse
- sublime text editor
- gnome terminal

The problem does not always occur, but once it is there, it stays there. I have not found the pattern that triggers this problem and I don't really know where to look...

Any idea ?

Comment: The contacts on the left button of a mouse wear out. I rarely had a mouse last more that 3 years. Check with another mouse (or change the batteries, if wireless).

Comment: @xenoid: thanks but no. It happens only in some specific programs. Other programs do not show that problem. Like darktable and firefox running side by side: darktable shows the problem but firefox not...

Comment: It just happened the same thing to me... AwesomeWM on Arch Linux. In my case it affects only Darktable.